# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when adding columns (extension table approach) in Acumatica ERP

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add additional fields "isInterestPenalty" and "previousInvoice".

here is my extended table script:

```
CREATE TABLE [ARInvoiceTableExtension]
(
[CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
[DocType] [char](3) NOT NULL,
[RefNbr] [int] NOT NULL,
[DeletedDatabaseRecord] [bit] NOT NULL,
[isInterestPenalty] [bit] DEFAULT 0,
[previousInvoice] [nvarchar](15),

CONSTRAINT [ARInvoiceTableExtension_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
[CompanyID] ASC,
[DocType],
[RefNbr]
)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF,
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ARInvoiceTableExtension] ADD DEFAULT ((0))
FOR [DeletedDatabaseRecord]
GO
```

and here is my DAC for that.

```
namespace ContractPriceDetailsCustomization
{
    [PXTable(typeof(ARInvoice.refNbr), typeof(ARInvoice.docType),
IsOptional = true)]
    public class ARInvoiceTableExtension : PXCacheExtension<ARInvoice>
    {
        #region isInterestPenalty
            public abstract class isInterestPenalty : PX.Data.IBqlField
            {
            }
            [PXDBBool]
            [PXDefault(false)]
            public bool IsInterestPenalty { get; set; }
        #endregion
        #region previousInvoice
            public abstract class previousInvoice : PX.Data.IBqlField
            {
            }
            [PXDBString(15)]
            [PXDefault("")]
            public string PreviousInvoice { get; set; }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

The error appears in CT301000 because the customization targets that page.
I would like to know what i did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I already fixed it. 
instead of: 
public bool IsInterestPenalty { get; set; }
i used 
public bool? IsInterestPenalty { get; set; }

i need the "?"

Comment: Acumatica always requires all DAC fields to be of a nullable type. bool? or  Nullable<bool> in your cace